# How to get Binary Data to submit to REST API

Tags: rest-api, contentversion, blob, binarydata

I'm attempting to use curl and multipart message to attach files to a created record. I am successfully able to do so, however the file is corrupted when I view it. I think I may not be getting the correct form of the binary data.

`curl https://{baseurl}.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/ContentVersion -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=\"boundary_string\"" --data-binary @TestFileUpload.json`

```
--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content";
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "ReasonForChange" : "Initial Upload",
    "PathOnClient" : "/path/10840.pdf",
    "FirstPublishLocationId" : "a0v7j000001TioYAAS"
}

--boundary_string

Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="10840.pdf"

0000000      5025    4644    312d    372e    250d    e3e2    d3cf    0a0d
0000020      2031    2030    626f    0d6a    3c3c    462f    6c69    6574
{other 4,000 lines ommitted from screenshot}

--boundary_string--
```

In order to get the binary data I tried 3 methods, one simply opening the pdf in sublime text. Another using the following command from my MacOS terminal ([this returns hexadecimal ints format i believe](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/od/)).

`od -h 10840.pdf > text10740`

Both of these methods resulted in corrupt pdf being uploaded. Any advice here on how to get the correct binary code would be helpful. I also use node and javascript and attempted to write to a text file.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let inputFile = '10840.pdf';

let outputFile = "test.txt";

let readOptions = {
    encoding: 'ascii',
    flag: 'r'
}

let writeOptions = {
    encoding: 'binary'
}

// fs.readFile(inputFile, readOptions, (err, data) => {
fs.readFile(inputFile, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  
  fs.writeFile(outputFile, data, writeOptions, function(err) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
    } else {
       console.log("The file was saved!");
    }
  });
});
```

Also tried using jsforce:

```
var jsforce = require('jsforce');
var request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

var connection = new jsforce.Connection({
  // you can change loginUrl to connect to sandbox or prerelease env.
  loginUrl : 'https://test.salesforce.com'
});

let username = {username};
let password = {password};
connection.login(username, password, function(err, userInfo) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
  // Now you can get the access token and instance URL information.
  // Save them to establish connection next time.
  console.log(connection.accessToken);
  console.log(connection.instanceUrl);
  // logged in user property
  console.log("User ID: " + userInfo.id);
  console.log("Org ID: " + userInfo.organizationId);

  let entityContent = {
    "ReasonForChange" : "Initial Upload",
    "PathOnClient" : "path/10840.pdf",
    "FirstPublishLocationId" : "a0v7j000001TioYAAS"
   };
  const file = fs.readFileSync('10840.pdf', {encoding:'ascii', flag:'r'});

  request.post({
    url: connection.instanceUrl + '/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/ContentVersion',
    auth: {
      bearer: connection.accessToken
    },
    formData: {
      entity_content: {
        value: JSON.stringify(entityContent),
        options: {
          contentType: 'application/json'
        }
      },
      VersionData: {
        value: file,
        options: {
          filename: '10840.pdf',
          contentType: 'application/pdf'
        }
      }
    }
  }, (err, response) => {
    if (err)
      reject(err)

    console.log(JSON.parse(response.body));
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately got this to work using the 'fs' utility and using 'request' library to send.

```
var jsforce = require('jsforce');
var request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

var connection = new jsforce.Connection({
  loginUrl : 'https://test.salesforce.com'
});

let username = {username};
let password = {password};
connection.login(username, password, function(err, userInfo) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }

  let entityContent = {
    "ReasonForChange" : "Initial Upload",
    "PathOnClient" : "path/10840.pdf",
    "FirstPublishLocationId" : "a0v7j000001TioYAAS"
   };
  const file = fs.readFileSync('10840.pdf'); // I let this use default encoding

  request.post({
    url: connection.instanceUrl + '/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/ContentVersion',
    auth: {
      bearer: connection.accessToken
    },
    formData: {
      entity_content: {
        value: JSON.stringify(entityContent),
        options: {
          contentType: 'application/json'
        }
      },
      VersionData: {
        value: file,
        options: {
          filename: '10840.pdf',
          contentType: 'application/octet-stream'
        }
      }
    }
  }, (err, response) => {
    if (err)
      reject(err)

    console.log(JSON.parse(response.body));
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The binary data must be in its raw form.

```
--boundary_string

Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="10840.pdf"

%PDF-rest of binary data here, with no line breaks, etc. It should be mostly illegible...
--boundry_string--
```

You may also want to read [RFC 7578](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578).

Edit: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/40c9284e91d209356395b43022ffc5cc) for an example of how to do proper `multipart/form-data` in Node.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about - how to get the raw binary of a file that's on my system. Any advice would be appreciated. I tried using node.js fs library readFile() and writeFile() but was unsuccessful. I'll post the code I used above.

Comment: @ShuaibAhmed Take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/40c9284e91d209356395b43022ffc5cc) (not mine, but an excellent starting point). You need to use Buffer.

Comment: will check it out - thanks, i also tried using jsforce, request. See my latest edit. It got the uploaded pdf to be the exact correct file size as my successful singlepart message call.

Comment: Got it to work! Thanks for your help - I used fs.readFileSync() from node and that must provide the Buffer data.

Comment: @ShuaibAhmed You're welcome, glad I was able to help point you to a resource you could use.