# File corrupted on sending data to create file via workbench using REST API

Tags: apex, apexrest, files, contentversion, contentdocument

I am trying to create a file in in salesforce via workbench. The file is getting created although the file is corrupted. I feel there is some issue in binary data. What I am doing to get the binary data is that I went to this link: https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file  and uploaded a pdf file to get binary encoded base64 data.

I did have referred this stack exchange link as well: [How to get Binary Data to submit to REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/361669/how-to-get-binary-data-to-submit-to-rest-api)

I have written header like below:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary="boundary_string"
```

I have written a body like below.

```
--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content";
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "FirstPublishLocationId" : "5008B000001YalDQAS",
    "Title" : "Marketinggggq123456",
    "PathOnClient" : "Marketinggggq123456.pdf"
}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="Marketinggggq123456.pdf"

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

--boundary_string--
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "corrupted", it's base-64 encoded. In order for it to have a chance of a successful transfer as written, you'd have to use the `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` [header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html). However, Salesforce doesn't support this feature when using `multipart/form-data`.

You need to send the binary data directly, something like:

```
--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="Marketinggggq123456.pdf"

%PDF-1.7...
```

Note that PDF has NUL (0x00) bytes, so you won't be able to just copy-paste it into the text area and have it work.

In other words, you'd have to write code in an actual programming language (e.g. JavaScript, Java, C++, Perl), or use a tool designed to transfer arbitrary binary data. Workbench can't handle this, but you should be able to test this out in Postman, which does support binary multipart/form-data requests.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. I believe we can send only one file via this. If I want to send multiple files with one API hit, then i have to zip the file first and then unzip it with apex using asynchronous code as with zippex library i was getting heap error. Am I right?

Comment: @Rabb In theory, you can use the [Composite API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite_post.htm) to send multiple files, or the [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/api_asynch_introduction_bulk_api.htm) to upload hundreds of files at once (but each will be limited in total size because of the limits imposed per file/job).

Comment: Thanks Sfdcfox !